# schema hasnt been registred for model (MEAN STACK)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I'm learning the mean stack and when I try to start the server using

```
npm start
```

I get an exception saying that:

```
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Firms".
```

here is my code Firms.js

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  author: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
});

CommentSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

CommentSchema.methods.downvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes -= 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Firms', CommentSchema);
```

as I can see the schema should be registered for the model 'Firms', but what can be possibly causing the exception to be thrown?

here's the app.js code with the mongoose initialization:

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
var Firm = mongoose.model('Firms');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

//var Crime = mongoose.model('Crime');



var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: Did you try to include schema in app.js like this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818071/mongoose-schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model

Comment: Yes i did try that

Answer (score 0):

Try using `module.exports = mongoose.model('Firms', CommentSchema);` also in your app.js try `var Firms = require('Firms');`

Comment: I also think this is a MERN stack question and not a MEAN stack.

Comment: How come?  I use mean

Comment: looks to me that this syntax is indicative to React and Not Angular?

Comment: @maria can you elaborate on _"dont work"_? The gist of the answer should solve your problem (provided that you substitute the argument to `require()` with a relative path to `Firms.js`, and `var Firms` should be `var Firm` to match the original code).

Comment: @robertklep i tried The code and all The others but Get same error

Comment: @LanceBarney the other models looks excactly like the firms model except the name, and they do work.

Comment: @LanceBarney that would result in not finding the module.