# angularjs service and response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

why is my `$scope.aux` empty, while the response is acually there?

response:

[image]

I have the following in the factory:

```
    o.getfirm = function() {
  return $http.post('/firms', null, {
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
  }).then(function(response){
      console.log("getting firm");

      console.log(response.data);

    return response.data;
  });
};
```

caller:

```
$scope.aux = testservice.getfirm();

console.log("checking");

console.log($scope.aux);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because getfirm return a promise. To get data try this :

```
testservice.getfirm().then(function(value){ $scope.aux = value });
```

Comment: thanks! will accept answer when im able to. Do you have time for another issue too?

Comment: Post your question and I will try to respond quickly

Comment: its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957777/schema-hasnt-been-registred-for-model-mean-stack

Answer (score 1):

You can use $q library to handle error also

```
o.getfirm = function() {
var deferred = $q.defer();
return $http.post('/firms', null, {
  headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
})
.then(function(response){
  console.log("getting firm");

  deferred.resolve(response.data);

 return response.data;
})
 .catch(function(error){
     deferred.reject(error);
 });
return deferred.promise();

 };
```

And controller:

```
testservice.getfirm().then(function(value){ $scope.aux = value })
                     .catch(function(error){//Handle error})
```