# ref to filed of collection instead of collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a schema like this

```
const Schema1 = new Schema({
  field11: String,
  field12: [
             {  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                title: String
             }
           ]
})
```

and another schema which has a field to reference to filed of the first collection as below

```
const Schema2 = new Schema({
  field21: String,
  field22: [
             {_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}, 
             {ref: 'Schema1.filed12'}
           ]
})
```

I need to populate `field22` in schema2. How do I need to do it.

The below query doesn't work for me.

```
Schema2.find(field21).populate('Schema1.field12')
```

Comment: There is a typo in `{ref: 'Schema1.filed12'}`...

Comment: It's not about typo. The ref like this isn't working for me.

Comment: getting error as MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Schema1.field12"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818071/mongoose-schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model

Comment: that's not issue bro. Issue is with ref to filed in another collection.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

> The `ref` option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population, in our case the `Story` model. All `_id`s we store here must be document `_id`s from the Story model.

You are attempting to store non-id fields as a reference that should point to subdocuments that are nested in an array of your `Schema1` model. This simply doesn't work.